# Nodejs with express, static dirname

Tags: node.js, express, underscore.js

I'm currently working on a web app, using node.js, express and underscoreJS.

I was trying to understand the difference whether I use this or not :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

The app seems to be faster with it, but I'm not sure that I fully understand the meaning of this.
The meaning aside, if I want to use it on my computer for tests, it doesn't work when I try to use the app with localhost:xxxx (xxxx being the port), I end up having an enoent error, but it works fine on the server, any idea why ?

Sorry if the question seems dumb, I just was assigned to this project and lots of work has already been done before I arrived.

Comment: It does what it says, serves static files. Use it if you need to server js/css/images.

Comment: Then why is it faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

is for serving static files in Express.

I recently wrote [an example of serving static files](https://github.com/rsp/node-express-static-example) on GitHub.
The [main application code](https://github.com/rsp/node-express-static-example/blob/master/app.js) is:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'html');

app.use(express.static(htmlPath));

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = 'localhost';
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('listening on http://'+host+':'+port+'/');
});
```

The line with `app.use(express.static(htmlPath));` doesn't make it **faster** to serve static files - it makes it **possible**.

Comment: Your example helps a lot, thanks. I think I got it now, also for the enoent error.